# как подключиться к самописной функции jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код типа такого:

```
<input id="val">

// ================

$.fn.myCode = function() {

  function changeVar( value ) {
    a = value;
    alert( a );
  }

  var a = 1;
}
```

Как мне передать значения от **input** к функции changeVar.
Пробовал прописывать в html код на onchange, oninput ..., подключал через JavaScript типа

```
$('#val').on('input', changevar($('#val').get(0).value))
```

но ничего.

Как вызывать changeVar( value ) по вводу данных в input поле.

Comment: а к чему тут самописная ф-ция jquery ?

Comment: Я просто новичок в javascript / jquery и не могу пока правильно изъясняться. Если считать, что $.fn.myCode - это самописный плагин, то функция внутри плагина тоже самописная.

Comment: тогда просто поясните что вам нужно сделать, желательно в вопросе, не в коментах)

Comment: changeVar( value )?  как вызвать эту функцию из HTML страницы ?

Comment: никак , она живет внутри другой ф-ции и только оттуда ее можно позвать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```js
$.fn.myCode = function() {
  var input = $(this);
  input.change(function() {
    var a = input.val();
    console.log(a);
  });
}

$('#val').myCode();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="val">
```

`myCode` - это плагин для jQuery, который вы создаёте для работы над какими-то объектами.

Если вам нужно реагировать на изменения инпута да и только, то можно обойтись и без создания плагина, а сделать напрямую:

```js
<input id="val">

// ================

$('#val').change(function() {
  var a = $(this).val();
  alert(a);
});
```

Comment: если бы, но пишу именно плагин ( собственное отображение табличных данных с select ом и навигацией по клавишам.)  и стопарнулся на вводе поисковой строки. Пробовал рисовать input из плагина, но он работает Один раз, пока идет обработка плагина.

Answer (score 0):

в общем заработало таким образом.

```
$('#val').on('input', function() { changevar($('#val').get(0).value) } )
```

А вот строка

```
$('#val').on('input',  changevar( $('#val').get(0).value) )
```

никоем образом работать не хочет. Скорее всего какие то ограничения со стороны языка которые я не знаю пока.

Comment: В первом варианте вы добавли саму функцию в виде `function(){...}` - и она срабатывает после события. А во втором - `(function(){....})()` сразу разместили туда результат вызова функции, вот и вся разница). Если бы аргумент не требовался, можно было `.on('input', changevar);` - без скобок, т.е. сама функция, а не её вызов, и оно бы сработало.